# How do I import another git repository as a sub-directory with all of its history grouped at the HEAD of the commit log?

Tags: git, rebase

Given git repository A with files:

```
A/a.1.txt
```

and commit history:

```
A3333333333
A2222222222
A1111111111
```

and git repository B with files:

```
B/a.1.txt
```

and commit history

```
B3333333333
B2222222222
B1111111111
```

I want to import repository B into repository A as a sub-directory, with all of its history grouped after A’s history so that it will have files

```
A/a.1.txt
A/B/a.1.txt
```

and commit history:

```
B3333333333
B2222222222
B1111111111
A3333333333
A2222222222
A1111111111
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
# register the remote of the other repo
git remote add -f other url-to-repo

# merge the content from `other`
git merge -s ours --no-commit other/master

# read the content under the directory PREFIX
#git read-tree --prefix=somedir -u other/master
git read-tree --prefix=A -u other/master

# commit the merge
git commit -m "subtree merge"
```

The commit history will be not 100% as you asked,
as the other branch will be merged, so there will be a merge commit at the end, and the history will look more like this:

```
*   938762e (HEAD -> append) subtree merge
|\
| * B3333333333
| * B2222222222
| * B1111111111
* A3333333333
* A2222222222
* A1111111111
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the history were not grouped as I had hoped for.

My commit history was shuffled and looked more like this in the end:

`    B3333333333
    A3333333333
    A2222222222
    B2222222222
    B1111111111
    A1111111111
`

One way that I know is that if I then rebase A again, it has merge conflicts.

Comment: It may appear that way only if you look at the history by date. The commits are grouped, by the branch, which you can see if you look at the child -> parent relationships. See for example `git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all --date=local`

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate that you tried to help me. If I then attempt `git rebase origin master` the current state of the tree would have merge conflicts.  If I push, it would required a force, because it would appear as though I rewrote history, instead of added to it.

Comment: I don't understand how you can have conflicts, when the merged commits from `other/master` all affect a sub-directory that doesn't exist in the current branch...

Comment: I just updated my pre-conditions. I think it is because my real project, A and B, have files with the same name in the root.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the subtree merge strategy:

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/using-merge-subtree.html